# How do I stop meteor from doing npm updates?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm, meteorite

Every day when I run meteor for the first time, meteor goes out to the internet to check for updates in the npm packages.

If I don't have internet connection, I can't run meteor. This kills my productivity. I would like to force this update to not run so I can work.

My command line is:

```
NODE_OPTIONS=--debug meteor
```

The output is:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
npm: updating npm dependencies -- github, colors, aws-sdk, moment, string, urlify, sendgrid, airbrake...
iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
meteor-collection-management: updating npm dependencies -- mongodb...
kadira: updating npm dependencies -- debug, usage...
```

Now here is the additional puzzlement. My package.json explicitly specifies the versions of the npm packages.

```
more packages.json 
{
    "github": "0.1.15",
    "colors": "0.6.2",
    "aws-sdk": "2.0.0-rc13",
    "moment": "2.5.1",
    "string": "1.8.0",
    "urlify": "0.3.5",
    "sendgrid": "1.0.2",
    "airbrake": "0.3.8"
}
```

The list and versions haven't changed in ages. npm should have no reason to go to the web - it has local copies of the specified versions already.

Now of course there is a possibility that this update is triggered by a sub-dependency - which is why I would like to do:

1. Force an offline mode when running meteor
2. AND/OR tell npm to resolve all dependencies completely - so that it does not think it needs to do an update.

UPDATE: I am sort of working around this problem with https://www.npmjs.org/package/sinopia

These related? issues are also showing up on startup:

[Package.on_test runs even when not testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084633/package-on-test-runs-even-when-not-testing)

[Why does Meteor-Npm keep trying to get a package from the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084726/why-does-meteor-npm-keep-trying-to-get-a-package-from-the-internet)

Comment: You are seeing your Meteor packages updating the npm dependencies, which would be surprising to see as they should be cached.

Comment: Yes, I agree - I am surprised too. But why?

Comment: Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Comment: what if you run using meteor --production ?

Comment: I only ever see this the first time I use a local package, after that it's cached?!?