# Package.on_test runs even when not testing

Tags: node.js, meteor

This is what our app looks like when starting:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.     
>>>>> IN ON_TEST
meteor-collection-management: updating npm dependencies -- mongodb...
```

Argh. In meteor-collection-management/package.js (our own package), there is this:

```
Package.on_test(function(api) {
    console.log(">>>>> IN ON_TEST");
    Npm.depends({
      mongodb: "1.4.1"
    });
    api.use(['meteor-collection-management', 'tinytest', 'test-helpers']);
    api.add_files('tests/dbobject-test.js', ['client', 'server']);
    api.add_files('tests/enums-test.js', ['client', 'server']);
});
```

Why is Package.on_test running? I am not running in test mode not even in node debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The on test function just runs to build a dependency map, even though its not actually used. I see you've opened an issue on it too. Theres more info on what it does here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/a40a6273953c0e18eddcd67919754814461c5dd4/tools/packages.js#L1434

So it builds out .test, and needs to run the method to get the required files. Meteor needs to know what it needs before the project can run, which is probably why both run. (Package's need to be built into single files, as slightly different to the rest of Meteor)

Comment: I think you are suggesting something here? I feel like you have *almost* given me an answer. You have told me what is happening. But not how to avoid it.

Comment: I answered what you asked, `Why is Package.on_test running`. There isn't a way to avoid it apart from removing the `Package.on_test`, since the part of the meteor doing this is pre-build.

Comment: But if the app is not running in test mode, meteor should not care about what is specified in the on_test code. Even if the app is being tested, the package is not being tested. The package tests itself. This is why your answer doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Pat the step that this runs is early on in Meteors build tool. This runs before Meteor decides on whether to run in test mode or in normal mode. Before Meteor is able to build, it needs a dependency map on what to build. The dependency maps for test mode and normal mode are built at the same time, regardless of whether it is being used for tests. This is why it is always run regardless of whether it used or not. It's a bit like drawing a map, you need to draw it before you decide where to go.

Comment: It could be run only in test mode, its just built this way. I even referenced the lines where it does this, you could send a PR if you feel this behaviour is wrong.

Comment: Broken behavior: on_test should be on_test... not all the time. Anyhow good to know.